# igraph for python

Tags: igraph

I'm thoroughly confused about how to read/write into igraph's Python module. What I'm trying right now is:

```
g = igraph.read("football.gml")
g.write_svg("football.svg", g.layout_circle() )
```

I have a football.gml file, and this code runs and writes a file called football.svg. But when I try to open it using InkScape, I get an error message saying the file cannot be loaded. Is this the correct way to write the code? What could be going wrong?

Comment: Is it reading the gml file correctly? What is `g` after you read football.gml?

Answer (score 2):

The `write_svg` function is sort of deprecated; it was meant only as a quick hack to allow SVG exports from igraph even if you don't have the Cairo module for Python. It has not been maintained for a while so it could be the case that you hit a bug.

If you have the Cairo module for Python (on most Linux systems, you can simply install it from an appropriate package), you can simply do this:

```
igraph.plot(g, "football.svg", layout="circle")
```

This would use Cairo's SVG renderer, which is likely to generate the correct result. If you cannot install the Cairo module for Python for some reason, please file a bug report on https://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph so we can look into this.

(Even better, please file a bug report even if you managed to make it work using `igraph.plot`).

Answer (score 0):

Couple years late, but maybe this will be helpful to somebody.

The `write_svg` function seems not to escape ampersands correctly. Texas A&M has an ampersand in its label -- InkScape is probably confused because it sees `&` rather than `&amp;`. Just open `football.svg` in a text editor to fix that, and you should be golden!